# using ActiveRecord's query cache for non-query cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, rails-activerecord

How appropriate is it to store request-specific data in ActiveRecord's query cache? The way I see it, they've already done all the hard work, like making it thread-safe etc.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache['some']['var'] = 42`

There's also this, but it's not thread-safe: https://github.com/tricycle/rack-per_request_cache

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store`. The example below shows a memory store, but Rails also provides other backings including memcached.

```
cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new

cache.read("city")   # => nil
cache.write("city", "Duckburgh")
cache.read("city")   # => "Duckburgh"
```

Documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html

Comment: `Rails.cache` is great; however, I am looking for a per-request cache

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work for that. If you don't want to have values used across requests use a key that won't be used as part of future requests.